Is it posssible to ignore log with specific class name?
I'm using Nlog as a logger provider and nlog.config file with filters to ignore specific logs.
But I face with a problem to ignore logs with parameter className which equal to "Diagnostics":
{ "time": "2024-05-11 13:25:43.7657", "message": "Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/api/v1/someApi - - - 200 - application/json", "level": "INFO", "className": "Diagnostics" }
I tryed to use condition rule:
<when condition="'${var:className}' == 'Diagnostics'" action="Ignore" />
also tryed to use appsettings.json logging configs:
`
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Warning",
  "Microsoft": "Warning",
  "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning",
  "System.Diagnostics": "None",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Critical"
}

Are there ways to ignore logs by class name?
I'm trying to ignore all logs with className "Diagnostics"
I'm expecting clear log file without any logs with className Diagnostics

NLog Logging-Rules are optimized for doing filtering based on Logger-Name. Can you update you question with how you create the Logger and perform the logging? Also please include the NLog-configuration (Ex. from NLog.config-file). Notice it seems strange to use ${var:className} since NLog Config Variables should remain static.

How about create a rule which match the class name as Diagnostics and set its level to high level to achieve ignoring instead of using the fitler when condition.
